# Making a deep copy of boxed primitives

Tags: java, android, boxing, cloning

I'm trying to implement a `.clone()` method for a data object that consists of several "boxed" values (`Float` and `Boolean`). My first try was:

```
theClone.someNumber = someNumber;
```

But I figured this was just copying object references. So I tried:

```
theClone.someNumber = new Float( someNumber );
```

Android Studio didn't like that, and told me to use;

```
theClone.someNumber = Float.valueOf( someNumber );
```

So I did that, but now Android Studio is griping about "Boxing of already boxed 'someNumber'". Have I done something wrong? Do I ignore the warning? Is there an annotation that will suppress it? And what's wrong with using the constructor?

Comment: Why do you want to deep-copy value objects?

Comment: The purpose of a deep copy is to ensure that changes to the original object will not be reflected in the copy, so deep copying does not need to copy immutable objects. Since boxed primitives are immutable objects, you don't need to copy them during a deep copy.

Comment: @chrylis: they are configuration parameters for a program and I may want to save variations and recall them.

Comment: @Andreas: I didn't realize they're immutable. I have lots of statements like `void setSomeValue( Float newValue ) { someValue = newValue; }`. The compiler doesn't object. I want to be able to clone a snapshot of the values and save it, while continuing to make changes in the currently-active values. And again: what's wrong with using the constructor?

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need to make new instances of value parameters. There's no difference between one `Float` of 1.5 and another.

Comment: @RobertLewis You need to learn to distinguish between *the variable* (which holds a value) and *the object that it points to*. All of the wrapper types are immutable, which means that a specific `Float` can never change its value, but you can tell a `Float` variable to refer to a different `Float` with a different value.

Comment: @chrylis: you lost me. What would be the correct way to store a set of parameters in a data object, and be able to save snapshots of it, while continuing to modify the parameters in real time?

Comment: (The answer to "what's wrong with using the constructor" is that since value types by definition don't have independent identity and can't change, making unnecessary copies is bad practice. With `Boolean` and integral types, common values are actually cached to reduce duplicate objects.)

Comment: *"I didn't realize they're immutable. I have lots of statements like `void setSomeValue( Float newValue ) { someValue = newValue; }`"* --- You're mixing up the objects. The class with the `setSomeValue` methods is by definition *mutable*, since you're changing one of it's fields. That object must be copied during a deep-copy. However, the `Float` value assigned to the field is immutable. There is no need to create a copy of the `Float` *object*, when you copy the field reference value during deep-copy.

Answer (score 0):

if this is about storing values while being able to work with the "original values", there are several possibilites.
One possibility is to simply write the "old" values into an array.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

   int value = 10;
   ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   myList.add(value);

   value = 15;

   System.out.println("Old value was: " + myList.get(0));
   System.out.println("But new value is: " + value);
}
```

If this does not suit your needs I need more details

Comment: In researching `.clone()` I learned that if a class consists only of primitives and immutable members (like boxed primitives), then evidently all you need to do is implement `Cloneable` and call `super.clone()` and cast the result to your type.